# Ajuda com JSON e jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox, filtro

Olá. 

Tenho o seguinte código: **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newtech/xrkuoqhq/8/)** 

Nele eu tenho 6 checkbox de 0 a 5 estrelas, e quando clico em um checkbox ele filtra um json exibindo o hotel que tem tal estrela ate ai tudo bem. O problema vem quando seleciono mais de 1 estrela.

Ex: Se eu selecionar 1 estrela, 4 estrelas e 0 estrelas preciso que me retorne todos os hoteis que tem 1, 4 e 0 estrelas.

E supondo que os checkbox 1, 4 e 0 estejam selecionados, e se eu desmarcar o 0 preciso que so retorno os hoteis com 1 e 4 estrelas. E assim por diante.

Alguem saberia como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente o evento que está utilizando para verificar se um checkbox foi selecionado não é o mais correto (`click`). Para tal ação, é melhor utilizar o `change`:

```
$("input[name='estrelas']").on('change', function(){ ...});
```

Para solucionar o problema de retirar a acrescentar um hotel à lista final, adicionei uma variável que diz se o item foi selecionado ou não na função `filtro`:

```
function filtro(valor, selecionado) {...}
```

Esse valor vem da propriedade `checked` do elemento que está recebendo o evento `change` mencionado acima. No caso podemos referenciar esse elemento com o `this`:

```
filtro(value, this.checked);
```

Para mantermos o status de elementos selecionados entre os eventos de seleção, criei uma variável global chamada `hotels`, que conterá os hotéis selecionados:

```
var hotels = [];
```

Essa variável será preenchida dentro da função `filtro`, dependendo do valor `selecionado`:

```
if (selecionado) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(hotels, json.hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
      return hotel.hotel.qtEstrela == valor;
    }));
} else {
    hotels = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
      return hotel.hotel.qtEstrela != valor;
    });
}
```

Caso o valor passado para a função `filtro` tenha sido selecionado, utilizamos o método [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) para fazermos o merge de um array com outro array. Outra alternativa para esse passo é utilizar o método [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=control):

```
hotels = hotels.concat(json.hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
  return hotel.hotel.qtEstrela == valor;
}));
```

Caso o usuário tenha removido a seleção do valor, ou seja o valor `this.checked == false`, então apenas filtramos o array `hotels` e ficamos com os valores que não sejam o valor que o usuário removeu:

```
hotels = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
  return hotel.hotel.qtEstrela != valor;
});
```

Segue o JSFiddle com a solução: https://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/9/

Comment: Será que poderia me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224461/problema-com-filtro-jquery

Answer (score 0):

As respostas fornecidas pelos amigos @PanterA e @Everson, estão corretas e produzem o resultado esperado, porém eu faria uma abordagem mais simples....
Você já tem um objeto que contém as Estrelas Selecionadas, o próprio Array de Objetos CheckBox, sendo assim só é necessário verificar na função filtro, quais são os CheckBox Selecionados, e se o valor dele é igual ao do hotel que está sendo filtrado.

```
function filtro(valor) {
  var filtrados = json.hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {

    var objEstrelas = $('[name=estrelas]');
    for(var i=0; i < objEstrelas.length; i++) {
        if ( (objEstrelas[i].checked==true) && (objEstrelas[i].value==hotel.hotel.qtEstrela) ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

    $("#resultado").html(JSON.stringify(filtrados));

}
```