# Problema com filtro jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtro, filter

Tenho esse filtro em jQuery:

```
    var aeroportosida = [];
    Filtro.prototype.filtroAereoNomeIda = function(value){
        var dataa = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        aeroportosida = [];
        if(value.length == 1){
            var nm = value[0].split('- (')[1].split('|')[0];
            var nomev = nm.substr(0,(nm.length - 1));
            //var nomev = value[0].split('- ')[1].substr(1, (value[0].split('|')[0].split('- ')[1].substr(1).length -1));
            var precov = value[0].split('|')[1];
            Array.prototype.push.apply(aeroportosida, this.data.filter(function(pesquisa){
                var resposta = pesquisa.trecho[0].voo.filter(function(voos){
                    var nome = voos.aeroportoOrigem.sgIata;
                    var preco = voos.vooTarifa.tarifa.vlPagamento;
                    return nome == nomev && preco == precov;
                });
                pesquisa.trecho[0].voo = resposta;
                return resposta.length > 0;
            }));
        }else if(value.length > 1){
            $.grep(value, function(n, i){
                var nm = n.split('- (')[1].split('|')[0];
                var nomev = nm.substr(0,(nm.length - 1));
                var precov = n.split('|')[1];
                Array.prototype.push.apply(aeroportosida, dataa.filter(function(pesquisa){
                    var respostas = pesquisa.trecho[0].voo.filter(function(voos){
                        var nome = voos.aeroportoOrigem.sgIata;
                        var preco = voos.vooTarifa.tarifa.vlPagamento;
                        return nome != nomev && preco != precov;
                    });
                    pesquisa.trecho[0].voo = respostas;
                    return respostas.length > 0;
                }));
            });
        }else if(value.length == 0){
            return this;
        }
        this.data = aeroportosida;
        return this;
    }
```

Ele filtra de acordo com uma lista de `checkbox`. Quando eu seleciono somente 1 `checkbox` ele filtra normalmente, mas quando eu seleciono mais de 1 ele não filtra, e retorna `null`.

No parâmetro value eu passo os value dos `checkbox` selecionado em `array`.

Alguém sabe porque ele não consegue filtrar mais de 1?

Eu preciso filtrar um JSON de acordo com os dados do array. Por exemplo se eu passar dois valores no array eu tenho que filtrar o json pelo primeiro valor depois refiltrar o json pelo segundo valor.

Fiz esse filtro encima desse [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/9) que saiu [**dessa pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204773/ajuda-com-json-e-jquery)

**Atualização: O ERRO ACONTECE QUANDO EU UTILIZO O**

```
var respostas = pesquisa.trecho[0].voo.filter(function(voos){
```

**DENTRO DE**

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(aeroportosida, dataa.filter(function(pesquisa){
```

Exemplo: **https://jsfiddle.net/nmx4dcc8/**

Reparem que no: `{"sqTrecho":1,"voo":[]}` o `voo:` não pode retornar `[]`

Comment: o que vem no console.log(pesquisa)?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt quando uso o Filtro.filtroAereoNomeIda(["...", "...", "...]); com um array com mais de um dado ele retorna o pesquisa.trecho[0].voo igual a [] o que não pode acontecer. Se ele retornar assim ocorre erro mais para frente. Fiz esse filtro em cima desse: https://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/9/

Comment: Consegue montar um exemplo funcionando com sua função javascript?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt Segue um exemplo: **https://jsfiddle.net/nmx4dcc8/1/** Repare que em `{"sqTrecho":1,"voo":[]}` o `voo` não pode retornar `[]`